# I want to create list of list for example [[a,b,c,d],[a,b],[a,b,c]] by giving list of data

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list object that will collect the data and add it into a list of a list object, but every time the list object adds all data in a single list of data. Here is my output:-

```
  dataList = [a,b,c,d]
  pointDataList =[[a,b,c,d]]
  dataList = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
  pointDataList = [[a,b,c,d,e,f]]
```

I want this:-

```
  dataList = [a,b,c,d]
  pointDataList =[[a,b,c,d]]
  dataList = [e,f]
  pointDataList = [[a,b,c,d],[e,f]]
```

Here is my code:-

```
  uploadData = [[{date: 2021-01-06, count: 3}, {date: 2021-02-08, count: 2}, {date: 2021-02-26, 
  count: 2}, {date: 2021-03-08, count: 1}], [{date: 2021-01-06, count: 1}, {date: 2021-02-26, count: 
  3}, {date: 2021-03-03, count: 6}], [{date: 2021-01-30, count: 2}], [{date: 2021-03-06, count: 1}], 
  [{date: 2021-01-30, count: 4}], [{date: 2021-03-06, count: 4}], [{date: 2021-03-01, count: 1}]];

  for (int j = 0; j < uploadData.length; j++) {

  graphData = uploadData[j];
  barColor = colorList[j];
  extension = extensionList[j];
  print(
      "Graph Data List >>>>>>> " +
          graphData.toList().toString());
  print("Graph Data Length::::::::>>>>> " + graphData.length.toString());


for (int l = 0; l < graphData.length; l++) {

  datas.add(SalesData(graphData[l]["date"].toString(),
      graphData[l]["count"].toInt(), barColor, extension));

}
print("Data List:>>>>>>>>>>>> " + datas.toList().toString());
  datas.sort((a, b) => a.date.compareTo(b.date));
pointData.add(datas);

  print(
      "Point Data:::::::>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> " +
          pointData.toString());
 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is really tough to comprehend, but I think I spotted a mistake in this line: `datas.sort((a, b) => a.date.compareTo(b.date));`, it sorts and does nothing with it. What I think you need is `datas = datas.sort((a, b) => a.date.compareTo(b.date));`. Assign it back onto itself. I might be wrong though, not familiar with flutter or dart.

Comment: That's working fine in my code. No worries.@DFSFOT

Answer (score 0):

I found it where goes wrong. Here's the answer:-

```
          uploadData.toList().toString());
for (int j = 0; j < uploadData.length; j++) {
  graphData = uploadData[j];
  barColor = colorList[j];
  extension = extensionList[j];
  List<SalesData> datas = [];

  for (int l = 0; l < graphData.length; l++) {
    datas.add(SalesData(graphData[l]["date"].toString(),
        graphData[l]["count"].toInt(), barColor, extension));

  }

  pointData.add(datas);
}
```

need to just place the List of object parameter inside the for loop. i.e. List datas = [];